# Recursively listing symbolic links to a given folder with their full path

Tags: bash, command-line, ls

I would like to transverse my home folder and list all symbolic links which point to element having Dropbox in their path. The following command (plus some post processing to remove additional field of info, but that should not be difficult) nearly accomplishes the task

```
ls -alR ~ | grep -e "->" | grep Dropbox
```

In the output of my `ls`, the marker `->` precedes the path to the target of the symbolic link. In order to only get symbolic links pointing to something in Dropbox I pass the output through the final grep. However there is a problem: this way I only get the name of the symbolic link and not its full path. On the other hand using a command like:

```
ls -alR ~ | grep -e "->" | grep -E '(Dropbox|:)'
```

to keep the path listing of `ls` (in recursive searches `ls` first outputs the folder being listed followed by a colon) results in far too many hits. Any ideas?

Comment: Beware of the difficulties of parsing `ls` output if you have to deal with hostile file names (ones containing, for example, `->` or newline or even blanks and tabs sometimes).

Comment: Yes, this is why you should always use a real programming language (i.e. not shell scripts) for writing business software. But for a quick personal script this is probably OK.

Comment: Right, there should not be too hostile files, it is for personal use. How do I highlight code portion in a message? I have seen you have done it for me, thanks!

Comment: Highlighting of code — indent by (at least) 4 spaces. To do it quickly, select the code you want to indent, then press the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  (Rumours exist that control-K combination does it too; I've not used it.)

Comment: If you want to see hostile files, try running this script (in a junk directory — not one with valuable data in it): `ls -la |
while read -r line1 && read -r line2;
do
    cp /dev/null $'\n'"$line1"$'\n'"$line2";
done`.  It works 'better' if you've got symlinks in the directory. It pretty much guarantees that naïve shell scripts will fail horribly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffier So, while we have found an answer for my question, I have realised that, because of spaces in filenames, extracting the right fields with awk and processing them so to have a nice and clean      ln -s source target      is much more involved than it should be. So I was wondering: is this the way to go or should I use a different language? In case what would you advise?

Comment: You can build very reliable software in Python, which I would recommend in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -type l -print0|xargs -0 ls -ld|grep Dropbox
```

Comment: I suggest adding `-d` to the `ls` options so that if the symlink points to a directory, you don't get a listing of the directory. You could also consider `find ~ -type l -exec ls -ld {} + | grep Dropbox`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, forgot about the `-d` option - I've incorporated it into my answer.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Nearly there but it also lists files which have Dropbox in the path of the link rather than the target. I have tried modifying grep Dropbox to grep -E '.*->.*Dropbox' but it does not work - I do not know why. Playing around I have found that ls -l $(find ~ -type l) 2> /dev/null | grep -E '.*->.*Dropbox' > ~/Desktop/output.txt  works even if it is not very clean: ls complains about some stuff being not existent so I sent stderror to /dev/null

Comment: Actually my solution indeed fails on filenames containing spaces. Jonathan answer with the change I proposed on the last grep seems what is working best for me: 
    find ~ -type l -exec ls -ld {} + | grep Dropbox
.

Comment: OK, it was a team effort! :)